# Move one level of row to column and column to row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following matrix

```
c1st                1                   2          
c2nd                a         b         a         b
id1st id2nd                                        
bar   one    0.293321 -1.173014  0.045621  0.565526
      two    0.078300 -1.061078  0.332950 -0.563532
baz   one    0.578437  1.600270 -0.446242 -0.861848
      two    0.025128  1.189281 -1.487797 -1.044918
foo   one    1.791755  1.914113  0.334240 -0.698200
      two   -0.203376  0.321410 -0.445128  0.747344
qux   one   -1.375511  1.084954 -0.531304 -1.020195
      two   -0.094798 -1.066290  0.794430 -0.948802
```

generated by

```
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

df.index.names = ['id1st', 'id2nd']

iterables = [[1, 2], ['a', 'b']]
df.columns = \
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['c1st', 'c2nd'])
```

- How can I move `id2nd` to the third level of column?
- How can I move `c2nd` to the third level of row index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How can I move id2nd to the third level of column?**

Using `unstack`

```
df.unstack()
Out[482]: 
c1st          1                                       2                      \
c2nd          a                   b                   a                   b   
id2nd       one       two       one       two       one       two       one   
id1st                                                                         
bar    0.041343 -0.752158 -0.711644 -1.577000 -0.454746 -1.889375 -0.644445   
baz    1.684986 -0.423235  1.143991 -0.136017 -2.735571 -0.024267  0.393892   
foo    0.618897  1.356303 -1.153296  0.624918  0.693133 -0.804281  0.772482   
qux    1.722674 -1.025345 -0.406572 -0.207286 -0.030559  0.773167 -0.446558   
c1st             
c2nd             
id2nd       two  
id1st            
bar   -0.287645  
baz   -0.998609  
foo    0.679210  
qux    0.012901
```

---

**How can I move c2nd to the third level of row index?**

Using `stack`

```
df.stack(level=1)
Out[483]: 
c1st                     1         2
id1st id2nd c2nd                    
bar   one   a     0.041343 -0.454746
            b    -0.711644 -0.644445
      two   a    -0.752158 -1.889375
            b    -1.577000 -0.287645
baz   one   a     1.684986 -2.735571
            b     1.143991  0.393892
      two   a    -0.423235 -0.024267
            b    -0.136017 -0.998609
foo   one   a     0.618897  0.693133
            b    -1.153296  0.772482
      two   a     1.356303 -0.804281
            b     0.624918  0.679210
qux   one   a     1.722674 -0.030559
            b    -0.406572 -0.446558
      two   a    -1.025345  0.773167
            b    -0.207286  0.012901
```